# AngularJS watching an expression

Tags: angularjs

Say we have this expression

```
$scope.showButton = users.is_admin() && !document.is_provided;
```

And then in the same controller you have a button that updates the value of `Document.is_provided`:

```
<button ng-click="document.is_provided = true;">Provide document</button>
```

The problem is that `$scope.showButton` should now changed but it's not changing.

Updated: 
Plnkr showing simplified issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qk2jnHAmqsrNXSAjDYEk?p=preview

Comment: Why do you think the value of `$scope.showButton` should have changed?

Comment: I need a way to make it recalculate.. so I'm asking for the best way to do this using angular (instead of wrapping it inside a function and then calling it everytime I change the value)

Comment: Your Plnkr code does not match with your question. Can you please update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to add on to squiroid's answer and explain to you why it works. I'll provide a very simple way for you to understand, as this was a very common problem for me too when I started.

Angular has something called a Digest cycle. It is a series of functions that are called successively to make sure that if a variable A is two-way bound to another variable B (using ng-model for example), they always stay in sync (that is, always have the same value). Functions that angular provides (or services, that usually start with $, like $timeout etc), automatically start the digest cycle

So let's say that you have a variable A and you've bound it to the $scope variable B, which is equal to a variable C. You would expect C to be bound to A too, right? Because you think when you change C, B should change, and so, A should change too. But that is only possible when you start the digest cycle. The cycle will look for variables that need to be updated, and will update them. However, by simply changing the value of C, you will never trigger the digest cycle, and so your change will never propagate to A.

What you do when you put a variable in $watch is (as the $ suggests), you forcefully start a digest cycle. So now when you change C, you start the cycle, it tracks down that it needs to update A too, and that's why it works.

In your example, $scope.showButton is bound to document.is_provided. Now you're using a non-angular function to change the value of document.is_provided. This means that you do not trigger the digest cycle, and that means your change will never be propagated to $scope.showButton. Therefore, showButton always remains false.

And of course, an example to help you understand:
http://jsbin.com/vojoso/edit?js,console,output

Watch the console. I've added logs to help you understand.
Comment out the $watch statement and see what happens.
Try understanding it and then doing it yourself, you'll get it.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: That's great thanks! Actually what I didn't understand was how they were able to make it work without the $watch.. and using the var main = this;
Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think they are somehow saving the state of the controller?  I have to say, I don't think I've ever seen this kind of code. Sorry. :/

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but you can watch on it:-

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return Users.is_admin() && !Document.is_provided;
},fuction(newVal){
$scope.showButton =newVal;
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This worked as well! But I'd prefer to see how we can make it work without $watch

Comment: I don't get this. What it is being watched in here? Mind to explain?

Comment: @geckob the first argument is the expression that should be watched (in this case it is a function which returns true or false), if the return value is true (that means both Users.is_admin() and !Document.is_provided is true) the $scope.showButton gets true. So Angular supervises those two "to-be-watched"-values of Users.is_admin() and Document.is_provided. Normally you would wacht only one value like $scope.$watch('scopesVariable', function(newVal, oldVal){...}), but in general it is also possible to define a function, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 2):

Here is good article about [$scope.$watch](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html), it should help to understand how to solve your problem.

It you need bigger answer add code which will explain `Document` variable, and your REST service.

**UPD:** I see you changed you original question. I suppose you have trouble with controller. Try do not use `$scope` implicitly, use `data` attribute as sad [angular code style](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers)

Also show the part in you template where you connect controller.

**UPD 2:** You have some misunderstanding of my words, so I modified your [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/px4vPBRSEeaCFueNLy5K?p=preview)

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <body ng-controller="MainController as main">

    <div ng-show="main.data.document.is_provided">visible</div>
    <button ng-click="main.hide()">Hide</button>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" 
            src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js" 
            data-semver="1.4.1"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular
  .module('plunker', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController() {
    var main = this;

    this.data = {
      document: {
        is_provided: true
      }
    };

    this.hide = hide;

    function hide() {
      main.data.document.is_provided = false;
    }
}
```

You have one problem inside `ng-click`, as there should be function execution. Also you are using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I created a working plnkr to show you the issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Qk2jnHAmqsrNXSAjDYEk?p=preview

Comment: The OP uses `$scope` explicitly. What `data` attribute do you mean?

Comment: I added them after he mentioned it

Comment: Can you please show me a working plnkr? I'm not able to make it work

Comment: @JadJoubran sorry for bad link, but code is full and you can try it yourself. BTW, link is fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It wouldn't matter here if I was using `ng-if` or `ng-show` it works in both cases. But the problem is I can't understand why your code is working. Is there an article that can help me?

Answer (score 2):

**The best way** (imho) to deal with this kind of problems:
Use `{{ anyObject | json }}` in your view!

This way you know if the reference you are using and the object exist in your scope. using `| json` gives you accolades `{}` when your object exists but when it is empty. If your object isn't available in your scope **noting** is 'printed'.

In your case, change the body tag to:
     `<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">`

Then, inside the html of this controller add:

```
DATA: {{mainCtrl | json}}
```

So now you see your variables! And you also see clicking on the button doesn't change the boolean variable.

With some extra debugging and rewriting, this works:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

var main = this;

this.data = {
  document: {
    is_provided: true
  }
};



$scope.hide = function() {
  console.log(main);
  main.data.document.is_provided = !main.data.document.is_provided;
}
});
```

And:
    `<button ng-click="hide()">Hide</button>` (note the brackets)

Comment: Note that you may get better readability with that debugging trick if you wrap it in `pre` tags: `<pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>`.

Comment: @Sander_P Thank you for your answer but I still can't understand why you are using `var main = this` is there an article that can guide me through this? I understand now how it works but I've never seen it before.

Comment: The reason this is in my code is because it was in your code :) Personally I try to avoid using code in my controllers as much as possible and put it in directives (dom logic) or services (business logic). Try to use a directive with a **link** function for this and use $scope instead of "this".